# Add text in a column of a Query

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select PONUMBER from orderinfo where custid = 45203
and orderstatus = 'picked'
order by preparedate desc
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
UPS  |  1
UPS  |  2
UPS  |  3
UPS  |  4
UPS  |  5
```

I Basically want to add a column with a static word, UPS.  I will be outputting to CSV.

Comment: please provide table schema

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
select 'UPS', PONUMBER 
from orderinfo where custid = 45203
and orderstatus = 'picked'
order by preparedate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

If you want Separate columns then try this

```
SELECT 'UPS',PONUMBER 
FROM orderinfo 
WHERE custid = 45203 AND orderstatus = 'picked'
ORDER BY preparedate desc
```

If you want that in same column then try this

```
SELECT 'UPS  |' + CAST(PONUMBER AS VARCHAR(10)) 
FROM orderinfo 
WHERE custid = 45203 AND orderstatus = 'picked'
ORDER BY preparedate desc
```